# Python, Tkinter - DropDown Menu's

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I'm just trying to create a simple drop down menu as well as directing you to a specific frame if one command is clicked. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is. Can anyone guide me through or give me an example?

```
    # Redirects to a specific frame
def GoFrame(goFrameNow):
    FAQ.grid_forget()
    GoFrameNow.grid()

# Core knowledge content and design after login successfull (myGUI being main root)    
def Core():
    myGUI.withdraw()
    NewRoot = Toplevel(myGUI,
                       bg="powderblue")
    NewRoot.geometry('800x500')
    NewRoot.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    # DropDown Menu being created
    mainMenu = Menu(NewRoot)
    NewRoot.config(menu=mainMenu)
    CoreContentMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
    mainMenu.add_cascade(label="Support", menu=CoreContentMenu)
    CoreContentMenu.add_command=Label("FAQ", command=lambda: GoFrame(FAQ))

# Creates FAQ frame to test
FAQ = Frame(Core)
Label(FAQ, text="Testing").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: `FAQ = Frame(Core)`: The first parameter to all Tkinter widget constructors is the parent widget or window - but you're passing a function.  It's a function that doesn't even return anything, so this isn't just a matter of forgetting the `()` to actually call the function.  I'm not sure what that was supposed to accomplish.

Comment: This question looks identical to the previous question you asked. How is this question different?